# AutomaticChallenge not working for CookieAuthentication in ASP.NET MVC Core with Azure AD sample

Tags: asp.net-core, openid, azure-active-directory

I am slightly altering the code from the [Integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/). I can run the application successfully, and if I click the "Log in" link then I correctly get redirected to the Azure AD sign-in page.

However, I also would like for the application to automatically redirect me to the login page if I try to access a route that is protected with the `Authorize` attribute. I have added the `[Authorize]` attribute to the `HomeController`'s `Contact` action, but if I try to access this without being logged in, I do not get redirected to the login page. If I access the contact page while logged in then it displays correctly.

I have updated the `Startup.cs` file as follows:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    LoginPath = "/Account/Login"
});
```

But even with these changes, I don't get redirected to the login page. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I do a test on my side, the sample works fine, if I add [Authorize] attribute to controller action and then call this action without login, it will redirect to login page. You modified the sample code, could you share us your code with your updating for reproduce the issue?

Comment: You also don't mention what actually happens when you execute the contact action when not logged in.  You simply say that you don't get redirected to the login page.  Please post all of your mods as well as what errors or behaviors you're seeing.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've found the answer and noted it. Just FYI, when I was having the issue it manifested itself as the page being blank, with the browser showing the /Home/Contact URL in the address bar. Also the F12 tools showed the page was getting a 401 Unauthorized response code. But as noted below, this seems to be a change in version 1.1.0 of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem. The sample references version 1.0.0 of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies. I had upgraded the package to version 1.1.0, and [hit the issue described here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1062). Specifically, in version 1.1.0 of this package the AutomaticChallenge behaviour changed when using multiple authentication providers (which is what the sample does).

I was able to work around the change by updating the sample's Startup.cs file's Configure method as follows:

Change the line that calls `app.UseCookieAuthentication` to

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

And in the call to `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`, add this line:

```
AutomaticChallenge = false
```